# Can someone explain one of the algorithms that solves this Google Code Jam problem?

Tags: algorithm

I'm referring to [Shopping Plan problem](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/dashboard?c=32003#s=p3) from the Practice Problems. Here is a link to [the solutions page](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/scoreboard?c=32003#vf=1).

Comment: Does anyone have a link to the problem statement ?  The links are now broken, and I can not find those "practice problems" from 2008 in the [archive](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/archive/2008)

Answer (score 2):

Without looking at the solutions, this appears to be a standard [DP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Each state is represented by the list of items left to buy (`2^15` combinations) and current position of the car (`50` stores + `1` original position = `51` possible options).

Transition from one state to others is easy.

```
def minCost(itemsLeft, currentPosition)
    current_minimum = INFINITY

    for (each store in the list) {
        if (store.containsSomeOf(itemsLeft)) {
            candidate = minCost(itemsLeft - store.items, store)  
                     + cost_of_items_bought_at_store + cost_of_driving
            current_minimum = min(current_minimum, candidate)
        }
    }

    return current_minimum
end
```

Naturally, `itemList` is represented as a bitmask and not an actual list.

You'll need to consider perishable items also, but that's purely technical.

Finally, you'll need to either apply [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to recursion or rewrite it as pure DP.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, and it works well for the small problem set, but doesn't work at all for the large one. Of course the low level isn't optimized, I'm using Set<Integer> a lot where one could use a custom data structure to handle intsets. I see that the top solutions are written in C/++, I wonder how much of the inefficiency comes from the language, and how much from low level implementation details.

Comment: @ripper234 If you're using `Set<Integer>`, it isn't language's fault :)  You can employ array, something like `new int[1<<15][51]`, to memorize results.